# How to convert Char to Int in Haskell WITHOUT IMPORT anything?

Tags: haskell

Following is a part of my code:

```
expand :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
expand "" = []
expand (a:b:xs) = [(a,digitToInt b)] ++ expand xs
```

The aim of the expand function is just get a string like this form `"a1b2c3d4"` and output`[('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('d',4)]`, my code can do this but have to use `digitToInt`, and need to add `import Data.Char`

So ya, if I don't wanna use any `import` keywords, how can I convert `Char` to `Int`.

Comment: Why do to want to avoid `import`? Then the only way is to write `digitToInt` by yourself.

Comment: @m0nhawk You could use `digitToInt` fully qualified: `Data.Char.digitToInt`. Technically, that doesn't require any import :p

Answer (score 3):

As there are only ten valid digits in your usual ASCII code, why don't you write the function yourself? You can make it non-partial while you're at it:

```
digitToInt :: Char -> Maybe Int
digitToInt c = lookup c (zip ['0'..'9'] [0..9])
```

Comment: This should be the way but it would be nicer to return the provided argument itself if not a digit character or an integer instead of Just integer

Comment: That's equivalent, as in the difference between [prism](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:prism) and [prism'](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:prism-39-).

Comment: @Redu I think that's mostly personal preference. If you want to transform a `a -> Maybe b` into a `a -> Either a b`, you can just use `liftEither f c = maybe (Left c) Right (f c)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `fromEnum`, e.g.

```
> fromEnum '5' - fromEnum '0'
5
```

Watch out for non-digit characters.

The best option, though, is to use the library function.